# debugging a line in python

Tags: python, xdebug

I am not a programmer and I have found  a script in python. when I run the following line

```
info = {k: v.strip('"') for k, v in info.items()}
```

it gives this error:

```
info = {k: v.strip('"') for k, v in info.items()}

File "<stdin>", line 12
  info = {k: v.strip('"') for k, v in info.items()}

                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Would you please help me to debug it?

Comment: You are probably using an older version of Python than what that script requires.  What version of Python are you using?  That code uses a dictionary comprehension, which is only available in Python 2.7 or higher.

Comment: 2.6.6. how can I solve this problem

Comment: It's easy to convert that line to a form that will run correctly on older versions of Python, but if that script was written for Python 3 it may contain more code that also requires conversion.

Answer (score 0):

A Python 2.6 version of that line is

```
info = dict((k, v.strip('"')) for k, v in info.items())
```

or, slightly more efficient:

```
info = dict((k, v.strip('"')) for k, v in info.iteritems())
```

But as I said in my comment, if your script was written for Python 3 it may contain more code that also requires conversion. In particular, if the script uses the `input()` function, both Python 2 & Python 3 have an `input()` function, but the Python 3 `input()` behaves quite differently to the old `input()`.

Comment: there are 2 lines with "info'. the following line is before the line in the question: info = dict(x.strip().split() for x in fields[8].split(';') if x != '')

Comment: and then the line in the Q

Comment: @ali: That line `info = dict(x.strip().split() for x in fields[8].split(';') if x != '')` is ok - it behaves identically in Python 2 & Python 3.

Comment: @ali: If your script contains lines like `print(something)` it _may_ be Python 3. The older syntax looks like `print something`, which is not supported in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Either move the [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) into its own loop, or upgrade to Python 2.7 or [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

```
info = {}

for k, v in info.items():
   info[k] = v.strip('"')
```